# Custom Javascript Light-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am trying to create my own lightbox for images on my website. Yes, I know there is lightbox2 and it is free, but I enjoy the challenge. I am having a problem with click events on the lightbox itself, I am trying to make it remove the lightbox, but the click event doesn't seem to register and I have no errors in google chrome's dev tools.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lbox").click(function(){
        $("body").append("<DIV class='lbox_container'><DIV class='img_container'><IMG src='" + this.src + "'/></DIV></DIV>");
        $(".lbox_container").width($(document).width()).height($(document).height());
    });
    $(".lbox_container").click(function(){
        $(".lbox_container").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you also provide the HTML throw both into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: I think you can use $(this).remove() instead of $(".lbox_container").remove(), but as @TylerCrompton Mentions, a jsfiddle would be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(".lbox_container").click(function(){
    $(".lbox_container").remove();
});
```

Use this:

```
$("body").on('click','div.lbox_container', function(){
    $(".lbox_container").remove();
});
```

You need to do this because jQuery doesn't register the .click() event on new items in the DOM, just the items that exist on the page when the document.ready function is called.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to wait to set your answer as the right one thou... Again, thank you! Another question, I don't want the click event to register within the img_container

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the click state for the lbox_container after it has been added to the page - moving the bind event inside the first click should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lbox").click(function(){
        $("body").append("<DIV class='lbox_container'><DIV class='img_container'><IMG src='" + this.src + "'/></DIV></DIV>");
        $(".lbox_container").width($(document).width()).height($(document).height());

        $(".lbox_container").click(function(){
             $(".lbox_container").remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your method worked as well, but Greg beat you to the answer :)